# Git push randomly fails

Tags: git, repository, collaboration

I'm coding with two other friends and we're all using the same repository. For some reason, git randomly fails for me, and only me.

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository
>   database .git/ objects

What's intriguing is that we noticed that when friend A pushes his code, I don't get this error anymore, and I can happily push my code as well. Now when friend B pushes his code, all of a sudden, I see this error again.

This is extremely bizarre -- what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm thinking a file permissions problem, but we'll need more details about your repository and how you connect to it in order to say anything useful. What kind of server do you run on? (Windows/Linux/other) What user owns the repository files? Do you connect over SSH? What user do you log in as when you connect using git?

Comment: Each of the three users have the same access, and connect respectively through SSH on their separate accounts. The server itself is Ubuntu.  Root owns the repository files.

The thing I don't understand is why another persons pushes should cause mine to fail, and another ones pushes to cause mine to succeed =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible ideas:

- Your git repository is not configured as *shared*.
- Your directory permissions are not quite right, and depending on who creates what subdirectory of `.git/objects`, you may or may not have write permission.  (This problem can be especially acute if your file server is configured not to honor group sticky bits on directories.  I got bitten by this one and it still stings.  As far as I know, if your server is configured this way, it's not possible for multiple users in different groups to push to a single git repo.)

It would be especially useful to know on which OS and filesystem your repo is stored and how the permissions are set up.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, we're running on an Ubuntu server, I'm going to fix up the groups real quick -- I had seen that earlier (the fact that object's are owned by the user and the user group) -- didn't put it all together.  Will let you know.

Comment: So far, this is looking promising (though we need to wait for our third coder to come back to be for sure)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on something Norman Ramsey said, about configuring your repository as shared: to do this, go to the repo and run `git config core.sharedRepository true`. This will tell git to make files that it creates in the repository group writable; after doing this, you should also run `sudo chmod -R g+w .` to make sure existing files are set group writable as well. Of course, all users who are using the repository will have to belong to the group that owns the files in order for this to work.